# Specify the number of blank lines

Tags: key-bindings, newlines

Upon leaving multiple blank lines (saying 4 lines of blanks), I have to strike four times of Enter.

Tried C-u Enter or C-3 Enter, it does not work.

How could specify the number lines like C-3 space?

Comment: `C-3 RET` works for me, in both Lisp Interaction mode and text-mode. What mode are you in?

Comment: work in org-mode @zck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `C-q C-j` after your prefix command.  `C-q` generally instructs emacs to insert the next key sequence verbatim.

Comment: perfect, thank you.